# TFS GIT - Get latest from master

Tags: git, tfs

We use VS2019 and Git.

Scenario: User1 created a dev branch from master (branch1); User2 created a dev branch from master (branch2). Now User1 updates changes from branch1 to master.
User2 is not yet ready to update changes from branch2 to master but wants to get user1's changes to his branch. What is the best way to do this, preferably within VS2019?

1. user1 creates branch1 from master
2. user2 creates branch2 from master
3. user2 makes some changes and merges to master
4. user1 is still making changes but wants to get user2's changes to his branch.
   What are the options available to do this?

Comment: User2 needs to merge master into branch2

Answer (score 0):

1.User2 can commit his changes to branch2 in the local repository.
`git commit`
2.Fetch the changes from remote repository
`git fetch --all`
3.Make sure local repository is clean, if it's not clean you can use `git stash`
first to make it clean
Then execute the following command
`git rebase origin/master branch2`
4.You might need `git stash pop`, if you execute `git stash` in step2

Answer (score 0):

When somebody pushed their changes to shared remote repository before you'd like to push your local repository, at this moment, we can call your local repository becomes **out of date**. And you need make your local repo current with the remote before you push the changes.

---

**GIT command**:

As default, simply run the `git pull` operation to re-synchronize your local repository with the **newly updated remote repository**. `Pull` does a `fetch` and then a `merge` to download the commits and update your local branch in one command, which can make your branch current with the remote.

---

**VS 2019**:

If you prefer to use VS 2019 to achieve the same goal, you can follow below steps:

1). Select the **Home** button and choose **Sync** in **Team Explorer** tab.

[image]

2). Select **Pull** under **Synchronization** to fetch remote changes and merge them into your local branch:

[image]

3). NOW, you will see the confirmation message after the pull operation completes.

[image]

Comment: If I synchronize my local branch (branch1) with my remote branch1, I will not see user2's updates which is in his remote branch2 and also merged to master. My requirement is to get latest from master (which now has user2's updates from branch2) to my local branch branch1. I think user2's updates from master (or from his remote branch2) needs to be pushed to my remote branch1 and then to my local branch1, not sure how to do this

Comment: @bdotnet Nope, the synchronize here is syncing the latest remote branch that contains user2’s changes with your local branch. After you resolved the conflicts, then you can push your local branch back to remote branch. Next, merge the latest branch1 into master.

Comment: I followed these steps and it said - Repository is already up to date. No changes to pull. I think this is because user2's changes are updated in his remote branch (branch2) and also in master while my remote branch (branch1) doesn't have user2's changes.  I think what is needed here is to sync between two remote branches (users2's remote and user1's remote) and then pull from user1's remote to his local